# Как лучше и правильно двигать сцену(карту) в игре?

Tags: разработка-игр, html5

Есть некая карта 2D, карта целиком не вмещается на игровое поле. Как можно сдвигать её, при прохождении игры игроком? 
Как вообще построены такие игры? Как карта сдвигается?

Comment: Вообщем, вроде бы как нашел решение, щас буду пробовать http://craftyjs.com/api/Crafty-viewport.html

Answer (score 2):

Гляньте эту статью, пункт "Draggable слои":
http://habrahabr.ru/post/168705/

Идея в том, что отрисовать карту на больший канвас, отображать только часть холста, а при необходимости его смещать.

Comment: Спасибо, идея понятна :) Проблема теперь в другом, игрушку пытаюсь написать на CraftyJS. Может быть есть в CraftyJS уже встроенный такой функционал?